# How can I interpolate a String that comes from a Database?

Tags: flutter, dart, string-interpolation

I'm using Firebase with a Flutter application and I need to store in it the value of a String that will be interpolated based on other values from Firebase.

Record in Firebase:

```
{
  'template': '$amount kg of $fruit',
  'amount': '5',
  'fruit': 'oranges'
}
```

What I'm doing:

```
String get amount => _snapshot.data()['amount'];
String get fruit => _snapshot.data()['fruit'];

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Text(_snapshot.data()['template']);
}
```

What I'm expecting: `5kg of oranges`, what Flutter renders: `$amount kg of $fruit`.

How can I insert the values from `amount` and `fruit` in `template`? The idea is that each record can configure how it will look, so another one can have `$fruit: $amount kg` or any combination of `amount` and `fruit`

Comment: You could do something like `_snapshot.data()['template'].replaceFirst('$amount',amount)` and same thing with fruit

Comment: Are you just working with this set of data?  If so, given that you know the data field names, you'd just do a replace of "$amount" and "$fruit" with the data for those two?  Or is it that the records retrieved from Firebase will potentially have different data field names (but always a "template" field), and you need to dynamically do the interpolation?

Comment: @Craig, they will potentially have different data fiel names

Answer (score 1):

String interpolation is done at compile time and so only works with constant strings. At runtime, a code cannot list variables around, so no interpolation is possible, which is good for both safety and efficiency.

As suggested by ibrahimxcool, use `replaceFirst` or `replaceAll` method in `String`:

```dart
_snapshot.data()['template']
  .replaceAll('$amount', amount)
  .replaceAll('$fruit', fruit)
;
```